# Sending local notification data to specific page in Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, typescript, notifications, ionic3

I am using cordova-plugin-local-notifications to schedule my local notifications and it's working great. I need to make a view expand in my HomePage if the app was opened from a local notification, but I am having problems sending data to my page.

In case the app was opened from local notification, this code executes in index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
      cordova.plugins.notification.local.on('click', function (notification) {
        console.log("notification ", notification);
        let data = JSON.parse(notification.data);
        //TODO: send data to the desired page (HomePage)
      });
    }, false);
</script>
```

I tried putting this piece of code in app.component.ts, where I am setting up my navigation stack and initial work with pages, but I keep getting `Cannot find name cordova`. If I add `declare var cordova:any` there, I get a runtime error `Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined`. So I decided to put this piece of code in index.html, but from here I don't know how to send data to my page? Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put code inside **app.component** file inside **platform.ready()** block.

```
 platform.ready().then(() => {
     this.localNotification.on('click', function (notification) {
        console.log("notification ", notification);
        let data = JSON.parse(notification.data);
        //Open page you want (Send data with push or root method)
      });
};
```